# How to set up and derive a type from an abstract tagged record?

Tags: ada

I'm having some difficulties getting my head around inheritance in Ada, and with some syntax.

My goal is to derive from an abstract type with a record, and use a different data type in the record field. Here's what I've been able to compile:

```
type Base is abstract new Parent.ParentType with record
    X:Access_Type;
end record

type Child is new Base with record
    n:Integer;
end record;
```

But I don't want to have this additional n field, I'd like to have X  be an integer in the child type. I can't get the compiler to be happy with it. Something like the following is what I want:

```
type Base is abstract new Parent.ParentType with tagged record
    X:Access_Type;
end record;

type Child is new Base with record
    X:Integer;
end record;
```

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to tag the base type which I think would allow me to reassign the X field. (Without tagging, the compiler complains of conflicting declarations.)

Can someone shed some light on this? I'm quite new to OO programming in general and I'm finding Ada's type approach more confusing than the usual class approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Base` has to be tagged, because you can't say `is abstract new Parent.Parent_Type` unless `Parent.Parent_Type` is tagged, and that means that any derived type such as `Base` must be too.

The problem is that, as you have it, any code that can see `Child` could see two `X`s; the one in `Base` and the one in `Child`. The compiler won't let you be ambiguous; when others read your code and see `My_Child.X`, how will they know which `X` you meant?

One way round this would be to make the full declaration of `Base` private, so that there's only one visible possibility for `My_Child.X`:

```
package Bases is
   type Base is abstract new Parent.Parent_Type with private;
private
   type Base is abstract new Parent.Parent_Type with record
      X : Float;
   end record;
end Bases;

with Bases;
package Children is
   type Child is new Bases.Base with record
      X : Integer;
   end record;
end Children;
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what problem you are trying to solve by changing the type of `X` in a derived type. As suggested in [*Ada 95 Rationale: II.1 Programming by Extension*](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/95rat/rat95html/rat95-p1-2.html#1), extension of a tagged type *adds* components to those inherited from the base type. You may be looking for a way to specify *parameters* for a derived type using [*discriminants*](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-3-7.html).

Addendum: It may help to understand that Ada's support for common [object-oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) principles is not limited to tagged types.

- [*The Ada Programming Language: Object-Oriented Programming (OOP)*](http://www.adacore.com/adaanswers/about/ada) outlines the historical perspective. Prior to the advent of tagged types, Ada was considered *object-based*, with strong support for data abstraction, encapsulation, messaging, modularity, and inheritance; tagged types expanded the support for polymorphism, and [later additions](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rat/html/Rat-2.html) refined the feature.
- [*A Comparison of the Object-Oriented Features of Ada 95 and Java*](http://www.adacore.com/knowledge/technical-papers/a-comparison-of-the-object-oriented-features-of-ada-95-and-java/) offers a detailed comparison with a (possibly) more familiar language.

Comment: You may have been thinking that `Child.X` would _shadow_ `Base.X`, as it would in Java but not in Ada; see  [page 13 of the PDF](http://www.adacore.com/knowledge/technical-papers/a-comparison-of-the-object-oriented-features-of-ada-95-and-java/).

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure you are not just wanting to nest some records ?

```
   type Base is abstract new Parent.Parent_Type with record
      X : Float;
   end record;
```

...

```
type child_rec is 
  X : integer;
end record;
```

...

```
   type Child is new Bases.Base with record
      C : Child_Rec;
   end record;
```

Which will allow you to refer to

```
My_Base.X;
```

and

```
My_Base.C.X;
```

Of course this can be done without any of the OO features too....